# Dual space of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ with $l^2$ norm equals $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces

As usual, denote $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}=\{ x : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \exists N \ \ s.t. \ x_n=0 \ \ \forall n \ge N \}$;  $l^2= \{ x : \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |x_n|^2 < +\infty \}$ and $\| x \|_{l^2}= \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} |x_n|^2 }$. I must prove that $(\mathbb{R}^{\infty},\| \ \|_{l^2})' \equiv l^2$.
 A hint for this exercise says: prove that for each $f \in (\mathbb{R}^{\infty},\| \ \|_{l^2})'$ there exists $y \in l^2$ such that $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} y_n x_n $ for every $x \in l^2$.
I basically have two issues: first of all I cannot understand why it sufficies to prove the previous assertion to conclude; when it comes to the assertion itself, the only two ideas I have is to use the fact that  $(\mathbb{R}^{\infty},\| \ \|_{l^2}) \subset (l^2, \| \ \|_{l^2})$, which is an Hilbert space, then apply Riesz's representation to an extension of $f$ and finally restrict again to $(\mathbb{R}^{\infty},\| \ \|_{l^2})$ or try to use the density of $\mathbb{R}^{\infty}$ in $l^2$ (but I don't know how). Do these ideas make sense? Any hint or comment is very appreciated.

Comment: Makes sense. Essentially, this exercise asks you to show a special case of "If $X$ is a normed space, and $\tilde{X}$ its completion, then $X' = \tilde{X}'$". (Well, to be precise, the restriction $\rho \colon \lambda \mapsto \lambda\lvert_X$ is an isometric isomorphism $\tilde{X}' \to X'$.)

Comment: Thank you, hope I'll be able to put things together, I'll try.

Comment: If you're not afraid of abstractness, I think the general theorem is easier to prove than the special case. Fewer concrete things that can get in the way and distract you.